# Formula solution program

Tags: java, netbeans, structure, multimap, file-io

Below is an example of the input I am dealing with:

A linkedHashMap with **String,Double** as parameters

```
NumericMap: { p=20.0, r=5.0, i=2.0}
```

And file input:

```
p = i * i * r
```

What I now need to do is take the file input and store it in the program as a data structure that allows duplicates and maintains the order of the items from the file, based on insertion. From there I need to be able to apply the doubles in the relevant order into the file input, resulting in:

```
20 = 2 * 2 * 5
```

From here I need to say:

```
If(the file input structure .contains("*"){
Double1 = the double in front of the *
Double2 = the double after the *
Answer1 = Double1 * Double2
}
```

So far I have managed to achieve all of this by putting the file input into a linkedHashMap as well, but linkedHashMaps do not allow for duplicate entries. Someone suggested to me to use a multiMap like so:

```
Multimap map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
map.put(key, value1);
map.put(key, value2);
List values = map.get(key);
```

But unfortunately this just returns errors. I have also attempted to do this with arrayLists, but obviously arrayLists do not maintain there order once adjusted.

Any ideas on what I can use for my file input to obtain all of the above and how I should go about doing it.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code your own multiple map class. Here is one of the implementation:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MultiMap<K, V> {
    Map<K, List<V>> map = new HashMap<K, List<V>>();

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        List<V> values = null;
        if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
            values = new LinkedList<V>();
            map.put(key, values);
        } else {
            values = map.get(key);
        }

        assert(values != null);
        values.add(value);
    }

    public List<V> get(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: So this will allow me to duplicate key values or will I have to change it to Map<List<K>, ListV> map = new HashMap<List<K>, V>(); . Also when I add this to a new project it gives me an error for **public class MultiMap<K, V> {** saying should be declared in file name MultiMap. Must this be a constructor, if not what are the naming conventions and why is this showing an error. Thanks

Comment: According to my understanding, you need to store multiple values for same key, so it should be `HashMap<K, List<V>>` not other way around. For second error, make sure you are putting the code in default package in a file named as `MultiMap.java`

Comment: Must have explained incorrectly. I need the map to be able to have duplicate keys. E.g  {p=20,i=2,i=2,r=5}. The value for each key should only be allowed to contain 1 number. E.g both i's should =2 and p should = 5

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to understand the purpose of this? Will one of the `i` eventually change or something? Having duplicate key violates the definition of `Map` data structure. You need some way to differentiate the one `i` from another.

Comment: That's the point I was trying to convey. The values won't change once input and duplicates must have identical values. I have already attempted having the file input in a map, and it didn't work due to duplicates. However my numeric map is not supposed to contain duplicates. File input must contain duplicates and maintain input order

Comment: @Digitalwolf Map will never allow you to have duplicate `key`..it just not allowed. I'm not really understanding your problem, if you might exapling it more clearly then I could help.